# grouping elements in the list based in sequential order

Tags: python, list, grouping

I am new to python. Got a complex task to work on.

I have a text file containing a sections separated by comments and commands are in between them. There are multiple sections in the files. I want to extract the commands related it's own section and create a list out of it.

Eample:

```
test.txt

#section 1
ls -1
sudo apt-get install vim

#section 2
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

output:

```
list1 = ['ls -1','sudo apt-get install vim']
list2 = ['sudo apt-get install ruby']
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You haven't actually asked a question, so which part of the task are you struggling with? It's probably best if you show the code you've written so far and explain how it's not doing what you're expecting it to. Then it's possible for us to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks Tim.

This was earlier code, i am modifying it based on the inputs given by people here.

  def extract(self,outfile,mode):
        f = open(outfile,mode)
        for c in self.contents:
            if not c.startswith("#"):
                commands = c.rstrip()
                #f.write(commands+'\n')
                self.clist.append(commands)
        f.close()

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a simple grouping exercise, which can simply be achieved by keeping track of a section start for indicating that the subsequent lines should be appended to a new list

**Implementation**

```
output = [[]]
with open("test.txt") as fin:
    #from itertools import imap
    for line in map(str.strip, fin):
    #for line in imap(str.strip, fin):
        if line:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                output.append([])
                continue
            output[-1].append(line)
    output = output[1:]
```

**Assuming your file contains**

```
test.txt

#section 1
ls -1
sudo apt-get install vim

#section 2
ls -lrt
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

**output**

```
[['ls -1', 'sudo apt-get install vim'], ['ls -lrt', 'sudo apt-get install ruby']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an initially empty list of sections. Every time you find a line that starts with `#` you append a sublist. Otherwise, if we encountered a section so far and the line is not empty, we add the line to the last inserted sublist of `sections`.

```
sections = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        if line.startswith('#'):
            sections.append([])
        elif sections and line:
            sections[-1].append(line)
```

Result:

```
[['ls -1', 'sudo apt-get install vim'], ['sudo apt-get install ruby']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for k, v in groupby(map(str.strip, f), lambda x: not x.startswith("#")):
        if k:
            print(list(filter(None, v)))
['ls -1', 'sudo apt-get install vim']
['sudo apt-get install ruby']
```

For python2 use `itertools.imap` and `itertools.ifilter`

You can create a list of lists with a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("test.txt") as f:
    out = [list(filter(None, v)) for k, v in groupby(map(str.strip, f), lambda x: not x.startswith("#")) if k]
print(out)
['ls -1', 'sudo apt-get install vim'], ['sudo apt-get install ruby']]
```

If you want then stored so you can access by name use a dict:

```
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import count
with open("test.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    cn = count(1)
    for k, v in groupby(map(str.strip, f), lambda x: not x.startswith("#")):
        if k:
            d["list_{}".format(next(cn))] = list(filter(None, v))

print(d)
{'list_2': ['sudo apt-get install ruby'], 'list_1': ['ls -1', 'sudo apt-get install vim']}
```

Comment: I'll correct it...but even if you use one-liner...i think it's too large to keep it in one line

Comment: @JuniorCompressor,  it is pep8 compliant and yields the correct answer so the downvote was still quite interesting.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor, you have to remember programmers are lazy ;)